# Lockheed draw rules

Tags: rules, draw

I recently played [Lichess](https://lichess.org/kqaAck5u)
game that left me confused.

My opponent had 1 second left on the clock when the game was suddenly drawn. There was no repitition nor was the 50-move rule invoked. Did the program cheat me?

Answer (score 2):

This was a draw by threefold repetition.

The final position:

```
6k1/pp1r2p1/2n4p/3p4/3P4/1BP1R3/PP3PPP/6K1 w - - 19 37
```

had been repeated three times in the game.

It first appeared after `32. ... Kg8`, then after `34. ... Nc6` and finally after `36. ... Nc6`.

Although players normally have to claim a draw by threefold repetition manually, Lichess performs the claim automatically if the time left on their clock is below some predefined threshold. Since your opponent only had 1 second left, this is likely what happened.